# Run custom javascript after page has completely loaded?

Tags: javascript

We have a site and want to push a search param into the search bar on the site.

```js
  var url_string = window.location.href;
  var str = url_string.split("=");
  var pn = str[1];
  document.getElementById('searchTermAll').value = pn;
```

The problem is that most of the page is generated by their javascript, so #searchTermAll doesn't exist when the page loads. Is there any way to attach this to an event handler so it runs after their js runs?

Edit: Even when window.onload and document.onload have occurred it's not done loading the page, most of the page is loaded in with their js after window and document have loaded.

Edit 2: 
[image: This is the text box I'm trying to force a value into]

[image: But this is all the document shows.]

Comment: There is no event since it is not a process controlled by the browser. The code should fire a custom event after it changes or you can use mutation observers to see when content changes.

Comment: How would I check to see that #searchTermAll is no longer null and to run my js?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty George I've done my research, I understand how to set it up to run after the page loads. That's what I'm saying, is that #searchTermAll doesn't exist after page load because their js hasn't run yet. It's not a duplicate, I've spent hours reading through event handling and stack overflow custom js threads and the answer to my question isn't on here.

Comment: @KyleBoehlen Well then the question is unclear: "We have a site" "most of the page is generated by their javascript" -- first it's we, then it's they/their.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty "This should be easy. We have a site that we use, and want to push a search param into the search bar on the site."

Comment: @GeorgeJempty That's how I typed it, it got downvoted for bad grammar so I accepted the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval` to poll for the existence of `searchTermAll`:

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var str = url_string.split("=");
var pn = str[1];
var searchBar;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    searchBar = document.getElementById('searchTermAll');
    if (searchBar) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        searchBar.value = pn;
    }
}, 100);
```

This will execute every 100 milliseconds (10 times a second) until it finds the element in the page; you can of course make the interval as long or as short as you deem fit.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but no such luck either :( Appears that when their script starts mine stops running. Seems like the additional script has to be started after theirs.

Comment: @KyleBoehlen Replace "Appears that", with actual debugging; for instance, you could add an else clause to the above if, and put a console/log statement

Comment: I already did, the script needs to be ran after theirs or it will kill it.

Comment: @KyleBoehlen Taking everything you have written in its totality, none of it makes sense (I'm not saying *you* don't make sense, but rather the situation).  I guess my last question is, how are you adding *your* Javascript?  Presumably from a separate file?  If so, can you open the network tab in Chrome developer tools to verify that it's actually loading?

Comment: I've tried using several different chrome add-ons. CJS, Tampermonkey, etc.

Comment: At this point, I'm fairly certain it's not possible and that the site was designed to prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: I added some pictures